# Calculus of logs: Find the value of k

Tags: calculus, logarithms

The equation of a line perpendicular to the curve $y = \log_e (2x − 1)$ has the equation $y = −2x + k$, where $k$ is a constant. Find the value of $k$, correct to $1$ decimal place.

I know that a perpendicular line has a gradient of $-1/m$ to the line that it is perpendicular with, but other than that I'm not even sure where to start with this question. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, did you mean $\log_e 2x - 1$ or $\log_e (2x - 1)$?

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I meant to put it in brackets

Comment: While I made the change, you could do so yourself by clicking on the edit button at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 1):

We are asked to find the point on the curve, where slope of normal is $-2$.
We know that slope of normal is $-2$ if and only if slope of the tangent at that point is $\frac{1}{2}$.
Now,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{2x-1}$$
Hence, at the solution point, $x=\frac{5}{2}$.
Hence, solving for $y$ coordinate,
$$k-5=\ln{4}$$
Now, find the value of $k$ in decimals.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: The OP should have had parentheses around the $2x - 1$, which will change your answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ok, I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I see that the brackets makes a huge difference. Thank you for your help.